# Количество скобок

Tags: c++

Вот есть программа которая считывает количество открытых и закрытых скобок. Все работает, до того, как в строке появляются пробелы. Как решить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char str[80];
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    cin >> str;
    int numberRound = 0;
    int numberSquare = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '(')
        {
            numberRound++;
        }

        if (str[i] == ')')
        {
            numberRound--;
        }

        if (str[i] == '[')
        {
            numberSquare++;
        }

        if (str[i] == ']')
        {
            numberSquare--;
        }
    }

    if (numberRound == 0)
    {
        cout << "Round skobok porovny\n";
    }
    else cout << "Round Skobok ne porovny\n";

    if (numberSquare == 0)
    {
        cout << "Square skobok porovny";
    }
    else cout << "Square skobok ne porovny";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что происходит, когда там появляются пробелы?

Comment: Приведите пример строки, на которой возникают проблемы, и какие именно? Пока никаких проблем не вижу.

Comment: А программа должна считать поровну ли скобок или сбалансированы ли они?

Comment: @arrowd тогда количество скобок равняется нулю, тоесть после того как встретит пробел перестает считать скобы

Comment: @PinkTux в любой строке, как только встречает пробел, перестает считать скобы в цикле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы **читаете одно слово** с помощью `>>`.

Воспользуйтесь функцией `getline`.

А вместо лесенки `if`'ов используйте `switch`.

И еще - вот тут

```
for (i=0; i < 80; i++) {
```

лучше проверять конец строки (вы же не всегда вводите что-то длинное!):

```
for (i=0; str[i]; i++) {
```

Вобщем, вот исправленный код:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char str[80];
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    cin.getline(str,80);

    int numberRound = 0;
    int numberSquare = 0;

    int i;
    for (i=0; str[i]; i++) {

        switch(str[i])
        {
        case '(': numberRound++; break;
        case ')': numberRound--; break;
        case '[': numberSquare++; break;
        case ']': numberSquare--; break;
        }
    }

    if (numberRound == 0) {
        cout << "Round skobok porovny\n";
    }else cout << "Round Skobok ne porovny\n";

    if (numberSquare == 0) {
        cout << "Square skobok porovny";
    } else cout << "Square skobok ne porovny";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не поняла) почему символы не являются скобками?))

Comment: Где? Впрочем, неважно. Смотрите, как правильно...

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый :)

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум - условие прекращения цикла неверное. Если длина введённой строки меньше 80 символов вы начинаете обсчитывать мусорные данные. Правильней было бы:

```
for( i = 0; str[i]; i++ ) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: да, но это проблему не решает)

Comment: @ДашаНовикова, вторую проблему уже описали выше. Перед подсчётом выведите значение `str` и всё увидите. А ещё лучше - учитесь пользоваться пошаговой отладкой, подобные вопросы уйдут сами.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cin >> str;
> ```

```
gets(str);
```

```
scanf("%79[^\r\n]", str);
```

> ```
> for (i=0; i < 80; i++) {
> ```

```
for (i=0; str[i]; i++) {
```

Comment: Ну что ж вы такое советуете - `gets`... :(

Comment: @Harry, а что не так с gets?

Comment: @Grundy Как бы это мягко выразиться... Он же не проверяет длину ввода. Перефразируя Труса, "Категорически не рекомендован к употреблению даже в дошкольных учреждениях" :)

Comment: @Harry, `cin >> str` тоже не проверяет. И что?

Comment: @Qwertiy И его тоже так применять нельзя, само собой...

Comment: @Grundy, про `gets` даже в `man gets` сказано :)

Comment: @Harry, раз ничего нельзя, значит всё можно :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, не просто "нельзя" :-) *"LSB deprecates gets().  POSIX.1-2008 marks gets() obsolescent.  ISO C11 removes the specfication of gets() from the C language, and since version 2.16, glibc header files don't expose the function declaration"*

Comment: @PinkTux, у меня нет `man` :) _LSB deprecates gets()_ - а вместо него что-то предлагают? или просто убрать

Comment: @Grundy Обычно в литературе по C советуют `fgets(stdin)`.

Comment: @Harry, держи scanf.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тоже метод :)